# signalr standalone server get user

Tags: signalr, owin

I have a standalone SignalR server where I want to get hold of the Context.User in the OnConnected event
In my mvc4 application I use FormsAuthentication. But when calling the hub the Context.User is null
Isn't it possible to get hold of the User in a standalone signalr service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [sample](https://github.com/gustavo-armenta/CookieAuthenticationSample/blob/master/SelfHost/Hubs/AuthorizeEchoHub.cs) uses Forms Authentication and its using Context.User